# Linq unable to hydrate an IEnumerable in a left outer join group by query

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a left outer join group by Linq query:

```
var query =
from iDef in taskDb.TaskDefinitions

join iParam in taskDb.TaskParameters
    on iDef.Id equals iParam.TaskId into NullableParameters
from iParam in NullableParameters.DefaultIfEmpty()

join iExecution in executions
    on iDef.Id equals iExecution.TaskId into NullableExecutions
from iExecution in NullableExecutions.DefaultIfEmpty()

group iParam by new { Definition = iDef, Execution = iExecution } into g

select new QueryDomain
{
    Definition = g.Key.Definition,
    Parameters = g, 
    Execution = g.Key.Execution,
}; 

    public class QueryDomain
    {
        public TaskDefinition Definition { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<TaskParameter> Parameters { get; set; }
        public TaskExecution Execution { get; set; }
    }
```

The query keeps throwing

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name  
'dbo.TaskParameter'.
```

I stopped right before the execution to examine the underlying SQL statement,  for some reason, it doesn't seem to select any fields from table TaskParameter

```
SELECT [t4].*
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].*, [t3].*
FROM [dbo].[TaskDefinition] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[TaskParameter] AS [t1] ON [t0].[Id] = [t1].[TaskId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS [test], [t2].* FROM [dbo].[TaskExecution] AS [t2]
    ) AS [t3] ON ([t0].[Id] = [t3].[TaskId]) AND ([t3].[AsOf] = @p0)
GROUP BY [t0].*, [t3].*
) AS [t4]
WHERE [t4].[CsType] = @p1
```

I simplified the query to make it easier to read.

The SQL works, but it didn't select any values from TaskParameter.

Anybody has any idea what happened?

At the end, I have three tables.  TaskDefinition is main table. TaskExecution may contain 0 or 1 entries indexing (FK) TaskDefinition.  TaskParameter may contain any number (>=0) of entries indexing (FK) TaskDefinition.  QueryDomain reflects the desired structure of the result of the query.  Thanks.